# How to check the occurrence of a value in a m2m field in Django?

Tags: django

I want to display a list of icons that were "purchased" by the user, for this i try to check if the user is in `icon.buyers`, but I getting this error: `TypeError: argument of type 'ManyRelatedManager' is not iterable` in line: `if request.user in icon.buyers:`.

Is there any other way to do this?

models.py:

```
class Icon(models.Model):
    ...
    buyers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
class MyIconsView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        my_icons =[]
        icons = Icon.objects.all()
        for icon in icons:
            if request.user in icon.buyers:
                my_icons += icon
        serializer = LicensedIconSerializer(my_icons, many=True)
        return Response({"my icons": serializer.data})
```

Comment: [this is documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *filter* the queryset, like:

```
class MyIconsView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        icons = Icon.objects.filter(buyers=request.user)
        serializer = LicensedIconSerializer(icons, many=True)
        return Response({'my icons': serializer.data})
```

This will make a `JOIN` at the database level, and retrieve all `Icon`s for which `request.user` occurs in the `buyers`.

You can fix the problem with `request.user in icon.buyers.all()` but that is *not* advisable, since then you create an *N+1 problem* where for *N* icons, you will make another *N* queries to the database to check the buyers *per* `Icon` object.